# mySQL comparing timestamp to current date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a field in my table called created_at that is a time stamp.  I am trying to write a query where is will give me data where the date in time stamp is the current date.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM visitors WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at)) = 
CURDATE()") or die(mysql_error());
```

I looked up how to get date from time stamp that is why I am using DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at)).
 My query is coming back with nothing found, but I do have created_at fields in my db that are todays date.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The query is correct, there must be some other reason why no entries are found.

Comment: i suspect its not a unixtimestamp

Comment: @Dagon what do you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The timestamp data type includes seconds so the times will never match. You need to trim the seconds from both the "created_at" timestamp and the current date/time (now()) before comparing so the you have a chance of matching just the date parts. For Example:

```
select * from visitors where DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y%c%d')=DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y%c%d')
```

Comment: what does the mysql DATE() function do ?

Comment: The Date function is supposed to trim the non date info off the timestamp

Comment: Then do select date(created_at),date(now(),date(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at)) from visitors and visually compare  the columns to see how they are different. Base your where clause on the syntax that yields identical columns.

Comment: Thanks, I tested it out several times and got the results for the current date